# Python regex match only group not all string

Tags: python, regex

I have list of MAC Address I try with https://regex101.com/ and it match all 3 address but when I execute it in Python, it print only match of group

```
text = """20:0C:C8:0D:51:FE
75:85:2B:2B:80:38
75-85-2B-2B-80-38
"""
x = re.findall(
    r"^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]?){6}", text, re.M)
```

- input : `['FE', '38', '38']`
- expected input : `['20:0C:C8:0D:51:FE','75:85:2B:2B:80:38','75-85-2B-2B-80-38']`

Comment: `re.findall` only outputs capturing group values.

Comment: Put parens around the whole thing and make the inner group non-capturing: `x = re.findall(r"^((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]?){6})", text, re.M)`